# How to update 1 Million documents in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

To facilitate reading, I made use of de-normalisation. This is how the workflow is.

There are two collections

1. Users
2. Events

Events has a start, end timestamps and status.
Start, End timestamps indicate when an event starts and ends
Status maintains if its Upcoming or Live or Finished or Cancelled
Status is updated by listening to every minute scheduler.

When a user registers for an event, I copy the event object under users/{user-id}/events. This is required as I need to fetch what events a user registered.

**Problem**

Consider there are 1 Million users subscribed for an event when the status is Upcoming. When the status changes from Upcoming to Live, I need to update all documents under users/{user-id}/events collection, for all users.

If i make sequential batch writes, it takes nearly 1000000/500 = 2000 batches and it takes nearly 15 to 30mins to update for one event change. I see it too much problematic as events increase.

I'm pretty worried about the limit of 10,000 updates to the whole firestore per second to use parallel batch writes.

How to handle this scenario so the the writes won't hit the limits and can be written as fast as possible?

Comment: Are you aware of the cost of this operation?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, just because of not having query capabilities with multiple fields (here start and end timestamps) I have to go through updating the status flags. I see this a very general use-case but not sure how others are able to solve it at scale!

Comment: Cloud task seems to be just a work around but still It takes lot of time to update those documents. By that time users may need to wait for 15-30mins in worst case to have their state change, which is in-fact not much acceptable.

Comment: Cloud task allows you to control the rate limit but not to speed up this operation. Firestore/Datastore aren't designed for processing/updating several documents in the same time, it's very efficient for working on one or few documents per transaction.

Comment: Exactly! Thats the thing i figured out. Do you have any suggestions to make this work? Like using some other database in parallel as a helper to the firestore?

Comment: Why are you copying the event object into the User? Why not simply the eventId? Optionally the event name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215652/discussion-between-ayyappa-and-guillaume-blaquiere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how fast your writes can be handled, you use Cloud Tasks to limit the rate of writes.  A full discussion is probably beyond the scope of a single Stack Overflow answer.  After getting acquainted with [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks), I suggest looking specifically at [configuring a rate limit](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues#rate) for the queue you will use to handle all the writes.  Tasks dispatched to a queue can invoke a function to perform the deletes.

Comment: I went through the cloud tasks earlier but not yet sure how it can solve as the same write limits apply here too. Also, In parallel to this background writes, normal db operations need to be performed too. However, Let me give a try again to see if cloud task helps. Thanks Doug!

Comment: Cloud Tasks doesn't have the same limits as Firestore.  Cloud Tasks will instead observe the limits of firestore, writing only as often as you choose.

Comment: Oh! But, I hit a blocker here as my events can be more than 30 days in the future which seems to be a limitation of cloud tasks.

Comment: I'm not sure why that matters?  Just schedule the work before it needs to be done, within the supported time frame.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I'm on it to use a cron to schedule with in the limits. Also, I just wanted to confirm your second comment If I understand correctly. Consider I use one task for one document update(Update to Live status update change), when using cloud tasks I don't need to worry about firestore write limits? Sorry if you already mentioned but i'm not sure how its avoiding the 10,000 write/sec limit.

Comment: Cloud Tasks will limit the rate at which your function executes, as you queue work into the task.  Just do the math to figure out to rate limit the task to invoke the function that writes docs within bounds.  Your tasks will have to represent small incremental items of work.

Comment: Got it! I see this is the best possible option as of now!